# How to return unit from an expressions in f#

Tags: f#, unit-type

How can i return `unit` from an expression in f#? For example:

```
let readInt =
        let str = Console.ReadLine()
        let (succ, num) = Int32.TryParse(str)
        match succ with
        | true -> Some(num)
        | _ -> None

    match readInt with
    | Some(v) -> Console.WriteLine(v)
    | None -> ignore //i don't want to do anything,
//     but i don't know how to ignore this brunch of the expression
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The (only possible) unit value in F# is written as

```
()
```

So your code becomes

```
...
| None -> ()
```

Answer (score 9):

Just write `()` as follows

```
match readInt with
    | Some(v) -> Console.WriteLine(v)
    | None -> ()
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind the unit value `()`, it is handy in many situations.

In this case, you could use `iter` function from [Option module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370544.aspx):

```
Option.iter Console.WriteLine readInt
```

It also highlights the fact that `iter` functions (e.g. those from `Seq`, `List` and `Array` module) will always give you the unit value `()`.